# How should I containerize a python script which reads a CSV file?

Tags: python, linux, pandas, docker, csv

I am running a simple python script with pandas, which needs to read a CSV file to give an output. I am able to run this manually, however when I try to put the script into a container, it does not run.

I created a Dockerfile first, using `gedit Dockerfile` inside a folder named **Python-test**:

```
FROM python:3

RUN pip install pandas

WORKDIR /mydata

COPY TestCode.py ./

CMD python TestCode.py
```

Then I built an image using build command and image named **python-test** `docker build -t python-test .`

Once built, I created a container and ran it `docker run --name pytest -v ${PWD}:/data python-test`

However, I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestCode.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(r'/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data/Book1.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File /var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data/Book1.csv does not exist: '/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data/Book1.csv'
```

The CSV file I am using is called **Book1.csv**

Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how should I proceed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your docker container, you're creating a volume with `-v ${PWD}:/data`. If the file Book1.csv is in your current directory when you run this, on your running docker container it will be accessible at `/data/Book1.csv`.

This part of the error

```
File "TestCode.py", line 5, in <module> 
df = pd.read_csv(r'/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data/Book1.csv')
```

tells me you need to change line 5 of TestCode.py to something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/data/Book1.csv')
```

Edit:

You asked, me to explain a bit more .
I'm no genius, so I would recommend reading the official documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), but here's a short explanation of what you asked about.

First, your Dockerfile.

This first line means your base image is python:3.
There are lots of images out there that are publicly available that are pre-built for specific use cases (like having the Python dependencies installed).
(see https://hub.docker.com/_/python)

```
FROM python:3
```

This means run the command `pip install pandas`

```
RUN pip install pandas
```

This means your working directory is /mydata

```
WORKDIR /mydata
```

This next line means to copy TestCode.py from your host machine to ./, which in this case is /mydata.
So you'll end up with the file /mydata/TestCode.py on your Docker image.

```
COPY TestCode.py ./
```

The `CMD` part defines some defaults for an executable container.
See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd for more details.

```
CMD python TestCode.py
```

Next, the docker build command. See docs -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/.

```
docker build -t python-test .
```

This means grab the Dockerfile in the current directory and use it to build an image, and name the image python-test.

Finally, the docker run command. See docs -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/.

```
docker run --name pytest -v ${PWD}:/data python-test
```

This means run a docker container using the python-test image. Name the contianer `pytest`, and mounts a volume of your current directory into /data in the container. (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only).

Again, the docs cover this much better than I do, so I'd take a look there.

Comment: Hey Thank you so much for the correction! I just recently started on docker and don't have much idea about it. I just created a Docker file and ran commands after looking up online. Could you please briefly explain me what I wrote in the Dockerfile, build command and the run command?

Comment: @Arrow I added some more explanation to my answer. Hope it helps and happy building!

Comment: wow this is amazing! thank you so much for the explanation. It helped alot!